# What would your own programming language look like?

Tags: compiler-construction, programming-languages, syntax, language-design

What would your own (I assume perfect) programming language look like? Give a small example and explain your **novel** ideas!

I'm really interested in the syntax.

Comment: This is incredibly subjective, but I really can't see any valid reason to close it.

Comment: I've seen a lot of negativity around subjective questions and have learned to tag it accordingly. There is a Hide this tag feature that folks can use on StackOverflow to hide all questions taged subjective.

Comment: Many of us actively work to clean up invalid questions on the site, so blocking tags (especially 'subjective') makes this more difficult.  That said, you should really edit this post and hit the community wiki checkbox -- this is what it's there for.

Comment: Frankly, if we have "Jon Skeet facts", I think we can have a "language design ideas" question, too.

Comment: Syntax is one of the more uninteresting portions of a language. Sure, it matters, but semantics and expressiveness are far more interesting.

Comment: @Michael E
The syntax decides the expressiveness of the language.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Jon is right in saying that “[d]ifferent tasks suit different languages and paradigms.” However, there are a few considerations that are largely independent of the domain. These mostly concern syntax but since code is read more often than written, I actually think that syntax matters.

For one thing, and something that many languages do wrong, it's completely arbitrary to base the syntax off C. C actually has an exceptionally bad syntax. I'll just pick two examples.

The first is quite uncontroversial: semicolons are unnecessary. Take the following code; the grammar is completely unambiguous and easy to parse for a compiler. Neither semicolons nor explicit line continuations are necessary.

```
answer = 42
fraction = answer * 2 /
           (answer + 1)
Console.WriteLine(
    "Some funny number: {0}",
    fraction
)
```

This is actually quite similar to Python but even more permissive: the definition of `fraction` spans multiple lines. This is logical since the first line isn't yet complete.

Another bone I've got to pick with C-like syntaxes are their largely implicit variable declarations. Instead of announcing clearly “I'm declaring a `variable` of type `Foo`,” all they whisper shyly is “<sub>`Foo var`</sub>”. Since `Foo` isn't even a reserved word in most cases, the programmer isn't offered a single visual hint here. I prefer VB's explicit `Dim var As Foo`, even thought he keyword used here is, well, quite dim.

(C++ actually makes matters much, much worse by introducing a lot of nearly identical and often ambiguous syntaxes that mean completely different things, from variable initializations to function declarations).

Another thing *my* language would have to have is static typing. It's true that dynamic typing *has* its uses but they are surprisingly rare. Even most “scripting languages” wouldn't really need them. I think that this is often confused with *implicit* typing which has rather more uses. Take (again) the example of Python. Why doesn't it offer static typing? It's already strongly typed, statical type checking would only be consequent, and would cut down on debugging quite a bit. The same goes for explicit variable declaration. I fail to see what advantages implied variable declaration offers.

So there we've already got an outline for a language:

- Clean syntax, avoid historical clutter. In particular:

  - No semicolons
  - No explicit line continuations à la VB
- Explicit variable declarations
- Static typing

Furthermore, I'm a huge fan of certain C++ concepts, such as general-purpose templates, RAII (i.e. avoiding garbage rather than collecting it), immutability and the concept of value ranges defined via iterators. I've stated elsewhere that I believe iterators to be one of the most fundamental innovations ever. Give'em a little lipstick and you won't even recognize the ugly beast that is C++:

```
for i in MyVector:
    print(i)
```

rather than

```
for (typename vector<T>::const_iterator i = MyVector.begin();
     i != MyVector.end();
     ++i)
    cout << *i << endl;
```

Of course I'm aware that the above syntax is offered by many languages. But they all only offer watered-down versions of C++' powerful iterator concept (to use C++ terminology, the only kind of iterators that most languages know are input iterators, which are basically the least powerful iterators).

At this point I should probably say that the sole copyright for all these ideas is mine, patents pending (in particular for the [`MayOrMayNotBe` operator](http://appft1.uspto.gov/netacgi/nph-Parser?Sect1=PTO1&Sect2=HITOFF&d=PG01&p=1&u=%2Fnetahtml%2FPTO%2Fsrchnum.html&r=1&f=G&l=50&s1=%2220040230959%22.PGNR.&OS=DN/20040230959&RS=DN/20040230959) that doesn't really compare object references).

Comment: Static typing is almost always premature optimization.  How much experience do you have with dynamic typing?

Comment: This has absolutely nothing to do with optimization (although that's a nice bonus). It simply makes you more productive (IMHO) because it strengthens the compiler's ability to provide meaningful diagnostics. My claim is that dynamic typing is credited with a lot of advantages it doesn't really have.

Comment: For the record, I've got extensive experience with dynamic typing. I've done web development in Ruby on Rails and PHP, I use Python and Perl extensively for all kinds of tasks and I've developed in VB6 for years.

Comment: -1 `the sole copyright for all these ideas is mine` Who looks on SO for ideas they can't use? Seriously, if your ideas are copyright, why post them under the CC license?

Comment: @Nateowami Uhm. That was obviously a joke. "patent pending" should have given that away immediately.

Comment: Oh! Sorry! I'd reverse it if I could...

Answer (score 37):

A little cryptic, but this is what i'd like:

[image: Legos!]

Comment: Programing already has a lot in common in with Lego (when compared with, say, sheet metal fabrication). It's usually 1x1 flat legos, but the similarity is there.

Comment: I would upvote you, but it turns out I already did.

Comment: In order ot make anything decent, one needs at least 1X2 flat legos. Anything less and all you can make are small towers.

Answer (score 10):

I have no concept of a "perfect" programming language because there isn't just one task to be performed.

Different tasks suit different languages and paradigms.

Comment: So we should only strive to create tailored languages for specific tasks? I can agree that there might need to be a seperation between low level languages (like c and asm) where you can predict the effects of your code and high-level languages.

Comment: We should (and do!) create languages which suit *categories* of tasks. Some tasks naturally suit functional languages. Some naturally suit scripting languages (and subdivisions within them). Others naturally fit OO better. Try to be perfect and you'll be a jack of all trades, master of none.

Comment: But there are no rules that states that a functional language cannot also have OO aspects. See Scala, Boo (opt. duck-t) and C#. They are definitely a jack of all trades and it seems to work perfectly for them. I would go so far as to say that the longer a language evolves the more features it gets.

Comment: But as it gains more features, it becomes more complicated - which is a problem, making the language non-perfect. I agree that C# et al are aimed at being general-purpose languages, but they're still not the most appropriate tools for *all* tasks.

Comment: I did write the I assume perfect sentence tongue in cheek. As I see it programming languages are about controlling the dataflow, which could be done in any language and task.  I also think we have a long way to go to find a sweet spot between features and complexity.

Comment: @Jon, from what I've seen, the complexity seems to be mainly from languages that must build in all features directly. Compare this to a simple approach that lets features emerge. So yea, if you add features the "C# way" it's going to get complicated. But that doesn't need to hold true in general.

Comment: Well, I'll remain skeptical until I see this mythical language which is better than all other languages at all other tasks...

Comment: It's not that it has to be better than _all_ languages at _all_ tasks, just that "best tool for the job" seems like an overused excuse for poor design.

Comment: Sorry, but this is a really corny answer. OP obviously asked for hypothetical language that is most likely of everything you love about all of your languages.

Comment: @LiraNuna: But that's my point: a language which tried to combine all the best bits of *all* languages would be awful, in the same way that a car which tried to be sporty *and* fit a family of 5 would be awful.

Answer (score 6):

It would look like C#. I would love to own Microsoft!

Answer (score 6):

My perfect language would allow me to ratchet up the functionality as I need it.  If I need to write a small straight forward utility program without classes I could.  If I needed to use classes I could do that also, and if I wanted to write a completely object oriented solution I would be able to do that too.  The linker would be smart enough to let me create small fast command line utilities (with no runtime dependencies) or the largest bloated OOP GUI app I could imagine.

The problem is that what I like has opposing goals and thus I've always been forced into using completely different languages.  I currently use in no particular order PowerShell, VBScript, PowerBasic, Java, and C# (and sometimes VB .NET, VB 6, C++, Python, and Perl).

Now if I could do it all with one C# like language that had global functions with no runtime dependencies when creating those small apps, but let me make full use of the power of the .NET Framework and Java SDK when I needed to, I'd be happy.

Answer (score 5):

Perfect programming languages tend to be found in science fiction novels. For example:

- Orson Scott Card's **Ender Series** - To create you must go to a different dimension and form a pure thought in your mind. When you return, it is.
- Robbert A. Heinlein explored the concept of world as myth in **Number of the Beast**
- David Brin's **Earth** has programming through sub vocals combined with eye and finger movements.

It all still comes down to the same basic quandary. Any programming language that does not force the human to learn a skill tends to limit the freedom of thought. Natural language is not good either since it has many ambiguities.

I wouldn't mind one that combines freedom with power and minimal syntax. I've recently started learning lisp, and it seems very good so far.

Comment: Add onto that `Hitchhiker's` concept of terminals - a virtual reality that you physically mold into data inside of the terminal and the changes take effect as you do them.

Answer (score 5):

Massive parallelism empowered by [Amazon Mechanical Turk.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amazon_Mechanical_Turk)

```
job = "Upvote this answer"
@price = "$0.01"
fork(10000, job, @price)
```

Comment: Haha: the trouble with the mechturk approach is that you have to deal with "processors" that give you the wrong answer and then sulk.  :-)

Answer (score 4):

I'm a big fan of C macros, but I thought it might be nice if you could write macros or "meta-code" in the same language you're using. (C is a bad example; this could be good in scripting languages.)

In these examples I'm using braces to identify the meta-code. You would be able to run the source through a "preprocessor" to expand the meta-code out. Otherwise it would just be expanded once at runtime.

```
print "Your product ID is: ", { print '"', generateGUID(), '"' }
```

or

```
lookupTable[] = {
                  /* insert code to generate table here
                   *
                   * This lets you modify the algorithm easily
                   * but speeds up the final program.
                   * 
                   * This would be especially appropriate in
                   * cases where you would otherwise type out
                   * the table as a literal (yuck)
                   */
                }
```

Now and then we have to write several lines of very repetitive code; can't think of a good example right now but this kind of think would also be very helpful in such situations.

Comment: This is what metaprogramming is all about.  There are many languages with native support (Lisp-family, Nemerle, etc) and some with it hacked on (my own MetaPy project).  Being able to run code at 'compiletime' (whatever that is) is incredibly valuable.

Comment: Other variants of this idea include Lisp (defmacro, syntax-rules), Forth, Prolog (term_expansion), MetaOcaml, and Template Haskell.

Comment: Bear in mind that this is more difficult than it looks, even in a language set up for it (like Lisp); Lisp macros are harder to get right than Lisp functions.

Comment: SO is So Awesome... my, what you can learn...

Answer (score 4):

It wouldn't be very different from taking the best ideas of Eiffel and C# (because, plainly, I don't have the knowledge to come up with anything better - I haven't studied CS in the first place).

However, my main practical concern would be go to **one step beyond the classical "source code text" approach**. I know this is (or sounds like) an IDE thing, but why can't I have a configurable code view with columns such as preconditions/body/postconditions instead of a "linear" form (i):

```
  function f
  // f's preconditions
  // f's body
  // f's postconditions
  end

  function g
  // g's preconditions
  // g's body
  // g's postconditions
  end
```

Why not (ii) - imagine this is a **table** (with borders):

```
f      f's parameters    f's prec      f's body      f's postc    f's comments
g      g's parameters    g's prec      g's body      g's postc    g's comments
```

And also, why can't I choose how functions "begin" and "end" (braces, keywords...) in style (i)? Why can't I instantly show or hide private or protected members? Why can't I instantly see the "flat version" with all the inherited functions inside? etc.

The point would not be to have one holy code file where you edit and then multiple "cool views", but to be able to edit and add code in both (i), (ii) and whatever form is most useful to you.

In a way, talking about "IDE" may seem off-topic here. But OTOH I think this is going to change the way we write and read code, sooner or later. And this will ultimately influence the way languages evolve. The future goals would be to enhance not only readability but also "understandability" and interactivity.

Answer (score 3):

I would imagine mine would be somewhere between [Brainf*ck](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brainfuck) and [LOLCODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LOLCODE) except with A LOT more [parentheses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheme_(programming_language)).

Answer (score 3):

Multi-media.

I want to be able to scribble some graphical symbols, quickly sketch connections and then flip to other modes such as typing where precision is needed.

I also think programmming languages should support people who don't think in English (yes, even Americans ..... joking!). I've studied enough Japanese and tried to pick up some Indonesian - I would like to see a language support people with different grammatical constructs and orders.

I raised a question at a recent forum I attended on the future of the web, asking a visiting Chinese professor if he thought Chinese written language would be more likely to enable a workable semantic web than English. He was intrigued by the notion.

A lot of SF I read talks about future UI's for computer interaction:

- data wands in David Drake's [Lt Leary series](http://www.baen.com/series_list.asp#LL) (some of which are available [free from Baen](http://www.baen.com/library/))
- multi-modal favourite sets of gestures and vocalisations in [Matadora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steve_Perry_%28author%29#Matadora) and other casual mentions in Perry's Matador series
- pen and gesture-based UI including signing to *seal the log* in [Fool's War](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0446602930)

Answer (score 3):

Python is pretty close to ideal for me... I would just get rid of some annoyances like having the self keyword... but with a good editor, Python can do amazing things very quickly...

Answer (score 2):

A language that features no structure or variables, just one function.

doEverything();//automatic generation of all content based on already predicted input

Comment: I was thinking the same thing. A language that reads the user's mind and does exactly what they want...what more could people want? Only down side is that all us programmers would be out of a job.

Comment: Well, I was thinking us programmers could keep it our little secret!

Answer (score 2):

I envision a language that must be told precise restrictions on input and variables and execution order, and so can be compiled into fast multithreaded (or clusterable) software.

And here's an interesting idea: imagine that all the "statements" within a "function" could be executed in any order at all. If something depends on something else, you need to "call" the dependency explicitly. This would make design for parallelism an integral component of the language.

Unfortunately I haven't invested enough imagination to come up with anything more specific.

Comment: Hewitt's Actors took something like that idea a long way.

Answer (score 2):

[Clojure](http://clojure.org/) is getting pretty close...

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what my dream language would look like, but I have a little improvement for C-style languages. How many times have I written something like this:

```
Node foundNode = null;  // need stupid null value here to keep track if it was not found
foreach (Node testNode in nodes) {
  if (testNode.YesItsMe) {
    foundNode = testNode;
    break;
  }
}
if (foundNode == null) {
  // create new instance
  foundNode = new Node(blabla);
}
```

I know there are more elegant functional ways for this, but sometimes you still end up with code like this. A simple "guard" statement would help here:

```
Node foundNode;  // no need to initialize anymore
foreach (Node testNode in nodes) {
  if (testNode.YesItsMe) {
    foundNode = testNode;
    break;
  }
} guard {  // we get here if break was never called
  // create new instance
  foundNode = new Node(blabla);
}
```

Comment: as for me: s/guard/else/

Comment: Python has this: for x in y: ... else: foundNode = Node(blabla)

Comment: (let ((found-node (or (find-if #'test nodes) (make-node data)))) do-something-with-found-node)

Comment: One year later I know but why don't you write: http://pastebin.com/eDcVCw6m if node is found, the value is replaced, if node is not found it was already set by the initalization part

Answer (score 1):

My ideal programming language, the code would be smart, it would tell me if it had a problem with another piece of code, we would sit down and talk and it would tell me what its problem was so we could work it out... I call it "EmotionPeople++"

Answer (score 1):

I would like a programming language that makes tools really easy to write correctly. Extract method, colorization, autocomplete, compilation, etc.

I want this to happen while still being easy to write and easy to read.

Answer (score 1):

It would look exactly like Scheme. Only it would compile to both IL and Java bytecode, and assembly so I could use all those libraries.

Answer (score 1):

One designs languages to meet specific goals.
Syntax and semantics should follow desired function.

In my case, I wanted a language with fine-grain parallelism,
that is, very low overhead per grain to allow small chunks of
code to be parallelized.

I've designed and implemented it on x86 SMP systems,
and it has been in use for about 10 years as the foundation for a large-scale
software analysis tools.

The main point was to allow me (us) to specify
parallelism easily:

```
(|| A B)
```

does A and B in parallel, and let the compiler
generate all the crud that makes this possible.
We didn't care about whether the syntax was
infix or not, so we went LISP style to avoid
arguments.

A paper describing the language and a number of
parallel applications can be found at
http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Company/Publications/parallelism-in-symbolic-computation.pdf

The paper briefly discusses how we didn't
succeed in avoiding arguments over syntax
in spite of our decision.

Answer (score 1):

I'll start with the key features:

- It should be a **[homoiconic language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoiconicity)** with powerful support for macro-based metaprogramming. This is an enormous advantage for productivity (see Paul Graham's [beating the averages](http://www.paulgraham.com/avg.html))
- It should **run on any platforms**, and have great support for **running distributed code**. Setting up a cloud of machines should be a simple task.
- It should be **open source**.
- It should have largest possible **library and tool ecosystem**. Practically this means you need to have access to the Java ecosystem, so it would probably need to be a JVM language for this reason.
- It should **support type inference**. Life is too short not to have the compiler sorting out the type details for you.....
- It should be **functional** with an emphasis on data structure immutablility. This is the future for advanced languages (I'm not disputing that functional languages are hard to master, but this language isn't for beginners....)
- It should support **interactive development**, preferable in a REPL-like environment where you can interact with the running (potentially distributed) code environment.
- It should provide excellent **lock-free concurrency** support. As we move into the massively multi-core world, lock based approaches simply aren't going to scale. Software transactional memory is *probably* the way forward.
- It should support **low level coding** where needed for performance. High level coding is great 95% of the time but sometimes you just need to manipulate bytes directly.....

Currently the closest I've found to my wishlist is **[Clojure](http://clojure.org/)**, which ticks most of these requirements.

Since the OP refers to syntax, I'll give a few code examples:

Proper variable arity functions, with support for large argument lists:

```
(+ 1 2 3 4 5)
=> 15

(apply + (range 10000))
=> 49995000
```

Interactive access to the compiler at runtime:

```
(def function-string "+")

(def function (compile-string function-string))

(function 7 8 9)
=> 24
```

Distributed code execution (MapReduce style). Note that this implies that the language / library is able to take the locally defined `some-long-running-function` and transparently distribute it to all the nodes in the cluster for execution *at runtime*.

```
(def my-cluster 
     (create-compute-cluster :nodes 100 :service "Amazon"))

(defn some-long-running-function [input]
  ....)

(def reduction-function 
  (fn [a b] 
    (do-something-to-reduce a b)))

(def lots-of-inputs (range 10000))

(distributed-map-reduce
  my-cluster
  some-long-running-function
  inputs
  reduction-function)
=> (whatever the result of the mapreduce is over the cluster)
```

Proper type inference (i.e. the compiler works out that my-function always returns a String and makes optimisations / inferences accordingly:

```
(def my-function [name]
   (str "Hello " name "!"))

(my-function "Bob")
=> "Hello Bob!"

(compile-time-type my-function)
=> [java.lang.String :not-null]
```

Comment: I can't find a point in your wishlist that Clojure does not already meet. :-)

Answer (score 0):

My optimal language would look a whole lot like Nemerle (minus the arbitrary restrictions).  Really it comes down to metaprogramming facilities; I should be able to arbitrarily extend or modify the language in any way I see fit (period) to fit the domain perfectly.

Give me macros that allow me to work on the AST of all of the code as I wish and I can build *my* perfect language.

Answer (score 0):

It would be machine readable/writeable, and it would be written by intelligent software that takes instructions by voice.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. this is a tough one. My tastes run towards the easily human understandable, and light scripting-style languages (though i do believe this could work for larger apps). See code snippet:

```
function Foo takes x as string, y as boolean //can add returns [return type] if one wishes to be explicit
    //explicit variable declaration
    z as number
    //explicit cast from boolean to number
    z is y as number
    //implicit variable declaration
    bar is 3 * 5
    //function call
    print x
    return z / bar //since we casted z to a number, it returns a number
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to see a facility for a function to include an arbitrary number of by-reference parameters and pass them through to a nested function call.  In .net, one could do this for any fixed number of generic parameters, via something like (two-extra-parameters version shown):

```
// I forget the C# syntax for delegates, since I normally code in vb
delegate void RefAction<T1, T2, T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 t2, ref T3 p3);

Point myPoints[];

void DoSomethingWithIndexedPoint<XT1, XT2>(int index, 
  RefAction<Point, XT1, XT2) theAction, 
  ref XT1 xp1, 
  ref XT2 xp2)
{
  theAction(myPoints[index], xp1, xp2);  
}
```

My preferred syntax would be something like:

```
delegate void RefAction<T1, T2, T3>(ref T1 p1, ref T2 t2, ref T3 p3);

Point myPoints[];

void DoSomethingWithIndexedPoint<ref ...>(int index, 
  RefAction<Point, ref ...>, ref ...) theAction, 
  ref XT1 xp1, 
  ref XT2 xp2)
{
  theAction(myPoints[index], ...);  
}
```

where the "..."'s would automatically be expanded by the compiler in whatever fashion would be appropriate.  Such a facility would make it possible to use Lambdas in many situations without having to generate closure instances, and would also make it possible to do code like:

```
  Interlocked.CompareExchange(SomeObject["George"], SomeValue, SomeOtherValue);
```

which the compiler could rewrite as something akin to:

```
  SomeObject.ActUponProperty("George",
    (ref dest, ref p1, ref p2) => {Interlocked.CompareExchange(dest, p1, p2);},
    SomeValue, SomeOtherValue);
```

Note that because the lambda expression would not use any instance members or variables other than those passed as ref parameters, it could be implemented as a static function and would not need to generate a closure.